# Form validation using jQuery-Ajax

Tags: django, jquery

When it comes to normal POST, GET methods, I usually know my way around.

However, implementing ajax-jQuery into my code to make form validation is proving a huge step for me to learn.

I have a form that has 3 fields: 
email, confirm email, and password.

I am using this form to register a new user.

form.py

```
class UserField(forms.EmailField):
    def clean(self, value):
        super(UserField, self).clean(value)
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=value)
            raise forms.ValidationError("email already taken.")
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return value

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):

    email = UserField(max_length=30, required = True)
    conf_email = UserField(label="Confirm Email", max_length=30, required = True)
    password = forms.CharField(label="Enter New Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(), required=True)

    def clean(self):
        if 'email' in self.cleaned_data and 'conf_email' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['email'] != self.cleaned_data['conf_email']:
                self._errors['email'] = [u'']
                self._errors['conf_email'] = [u'Email must match.']
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Html code

```
<form method="post">
    {{ register_form.as_p() }}
    <input name = "Register" type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

I would like that, before I press the submit button, to check if the form **is valid** and display any relevant **error messages**, by using ajax-jQuery methods. However, I have no idea how to start / do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look into http://github.com/alex/django-ajax-validation

There is some documentation [here](http://github.com/alex/django-ajax-validation/blob/master/docs/usage.txt) and [here](http://github.com/alex/django-ajax-validation/blob/master/docs/serving-ajax-validation-media-server.txt)

Comment: the material seems interesting I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

You might also look at errors handling with AJAX.
http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2013/11/ajax-form-in-django-with-jqueryform.html
It has an accent on how to do it with jQuery form plugin and a dummy views/urls config in order for your task to work. (At least very similar one)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also, take a look at [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94022/169503).